# How to assign value of variable with regex (bash)?

Tags: bash

I want to use regex in bash at line of variable assignment

e.g.

```
oldip="14\.130\.31\.172"
oldip_a="14.130.31.172" //How to use regex on this line.
```

How to use regex to del all '\' in $oldip? Then assign to new value to $oldip_a.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to use string replacement like this:

```
    oldip_a=${oldip//\\/}
```

Or something like that... Of course there's always some battle escaping backslashes!

A more obvious example:

```
    some_variable=${some_other_variable//replaceEachOfThese/withThis}
```

search for "replace all matches" on this page:

```
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html
```

Comment: I think you have a typo (extra `/` at the end) - should be `oldip_a=${oldip//\\/}`

Comment: That's why I threw in the _something like that_... Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I would have voted up your answer but i ran out of daily votes!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do it:

```
oldip="14\.130\.31\.172"
oldip_a=`echo $oldip | sed 's/[\]//g'`
echo $oldip_a
```

**OUTPUT**

```
14.130.31.172
```